# Spring MVC freemarker macro simplify

Tags: freemarker

I write a macro in freemarker:

```
<#macro Hidden name value >
        <input name="${id}" value="${value}" type="hidden" />
</#macro>
```

Then I use it in my web page:

```
    <@Hidden name="user_id" value=user_id />
    <@Hidden name="user_name" value=user_name />
    <@Hidden name="age" value=age />
    <@Hidden name="address" value=address />
```

`name` is always equals `value`, althougth `name` is a string, and `value` is dynamic var in `ModelMap`. I want to simplify the macor then I can use like that:

```
    <@Hidden name="user_id"  />
    <@Hidden name="user_name"  />
    <@Hidden name="age"  />
    <@Hidden name="address" />
```

so how to do modify the macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<#macro Hidden name>
    <input name="${name}" value="${.vars[name]}" type="hidden" />
</#macro>
```

But you can also use the <@spring.bind /> libraries to accomplish this: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/qpid/tags/pre-M1/java/java/management/core/lib/spring/spring.ftl